# Passing object to next element in linked list

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I have created an arrayList `treat` to show 5 instances of a treatment room, I have also created a linkedList `inTreatment` for the treatment room to pass 5 patient objects into from `queue`, however when I pass multiple objects to the linkedList they constantly replace the first element added instead of moving to the next element available. I believe the problem lies with the `inTreatment.add` line but i'm not sure how to reference the next available index. All suggestions are more than welcome. 
Below is my code for creating the array and adding to the `inTreatment` linkedList.

Creating treatment rooms array

```
public static void createTreatmentRooms() {
    for (int i = 0; i < treat.length; i++) {
        treat[i] = new TreatmentRoom();
        treat[i].setAvailable(true);
    }
}
```

Add to treatment rooms method

```
for (int i = 0; i < TreatmentRoom.treat.length; i++) {

        if ((TreatmentRoom.treat[i].isAvailable())
                && (Queue.queue.size() != 0)
                && (Queue.queue.getFirst().getTriage() != Status.NOT_ASSESSED)) {

            // add patient to inTreatment list for future sorting...
            inTreatment.add(queue.getFirst());
            System.out.println("taken to treatment queue");
            // remove patient from front of queue
            for (Patient p : queue) {
                System.out.println(p.getFirstName());
            }
            queue.poll();
            System.out.println("second queue");
            for (Patient p : queue) {
                System.out.println(p.getFirstName());
            }
            System.out.println("removed from queue");

            // if free, add patient to treatment room
            TreatmentRoom.treat[i].setPatient(inTreatment.getFirst());
            System.out.println("sent to treatment room"
                    + TreatmentRoom.treat[i]);

            // System.out.println("patient added" +
            // queue.get(i).getFirstName());
            // set treatment room to unavailable
            TreatmentRoom.treat[i].setAvailable(false);
            System.out.println("treatment room busy");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Treatment room is not available");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried going throught it in debug mode?

Comment: @ChrisBolton I'm relatively new to java and haven't covered debugging yet so im unsure where to start

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Comment: yes chris I am using eclipse

Comment: @cg91, is this just an exercise or you are planning to use this code in real life?  --- java provides in-built data structures like Queue/maps/set -- collections .. I would encourage you to use those.. usually they are well tested and bug free -- gives most of the functionality out of the box.

Comment: Static fields... static fields everywhere... XD

Comment: The nice thing with `poll()` is that you can use it where you call `getFirst()` to read the first one and remove it at the same time. No need for 2 calls. (you can move your printing loop above the addition to `inTreatment` if you still want to debug the change in your queue)

Comment: http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/eclipse-debugger/ this is a good tutorial on debug mode in eclipse. You should go ahead and look through it. It will help you out a lot in the future. You can probably skip the first few steps.

Comment: You might be misinterpreting the symptoms of your problem. What are the symptoms? What makes you think the first element of the `inTreatment` list is replaced? Also, can you post the code initializing the patients/lists/queue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might come from here:

```
queue.remove(i);
```

You're removing the element at index `i`, but that `i` is in the range of the rooms, and has nothing to do with the queue, does it?

You might want to remove the first element instead.

*Side note: there should be a* `poll()` *method that allows you to peek and remove the first element of your queue in one call by the way, but I'm unusure what type of queue you're using here, it does not look like* `java.util.Queue`.

Comment: `queue` is another linked list which I am calling the patient objects from. Yes I see that the `queue.remove(i)` is not correct and I have changed that but the problem still persists, is there something I need to change with the `inTreatment.add` method?

Comment: Can you update your code with your change? FYI, `inTreatment.add()` will add your elements at the end of the list, there is no problem in that. You might want to consider using `java.util.Queue` for your queue if you're using the java standard lib anyway ;-)

Comment: `poll()` actually exists on `LinkedList` as well, FYI ;-)

Comment: Code updated, at the minute the `inTreatment.add` method is replacing a previously added patient object with a new one in the same index of the linkedList, is there any reason why this is happening?

Comment: How do you know that? How do you see it?

Comment: ok it seems now I have the patients adding to the `inTreatment` linkedList. The problem now seems to be that more patients are being added to the `inTreatment` queue than are allowed. The maximum treatment rooms available is 5 and the number is exceeding this?

Comment: Well maybe you call the code you posted multiple times. If you never remove elements from the list, you inevitably end up with more than allowed.